# how do you create ease in reduction in value in javascript

Tags: javascript

This more of a math question than programming, but still applicable as i want it to be done javascript.

I am animating stuff and for i need to create reduction that goes from full value to zero per frame. But it should decrease  slowly at first and then increase up the decreasing amount as value gets shorter. And vice versa for ease out.

linear goes something like this:

`speed -= linear;`

others i don't know and i don't how to classify this one either:

`speed *= .8;`

[image]

i guess i am asking for curve that goes from 1 to 0 in square curve fashion but flipped

Comment: What type of stuff are you animating? Is this a physical simulation? Is the easing influenced by other factors?

Comment: just some random divs, nothing has to be precise, but has to look realistic. i cant use css animations otherwise i wouldn't have asked as they provide easein/out functions but i am using requestanimationframe and doing animation manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try subtracting your speed by a number that grows exponentially.

```
var a = 1;
speed -= Math.pow(2, a);
a++;
```

if 2^a is too fast, try a smaller number (greater than 1) or try incrementing the value of "a" by a percentage, ie

```
var a = 1;
speed -= Math.pow(2, a);
a *= 1.1;
```

Comment: glad I could help. fiddling with the variables should allow you to get the kind of decay you're looking for. If you want tighter control over over your animation speed, take a look at animation easing, like here [link](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/)

Comment: thanks that link is touching the origins..i love it.